# What does %T>% function mean in R?

Tags: r

can you please explain this pipe - %T>% with some examples if possible. I found only one example with the plot:

```
rnorm(200) %>%
matrix(ncol = 2) %T>%
plot %>% # plot usually does not return anything.
colSums
```

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/magrittr/versions/1.5/topics/%25T%3E%25

But from this and description I don't understand the usage.
Thank you

Answer (score 11):

Both `x %>% f()` and `x %T>% f()` run `f(x)` but the difference is that the first one returns the output of `f(x)` whereas the second one returns `x`.

**1) plot**. `%T>%` is typicaly used with `plot` or other commands that don't return anything.  Such commands are run for their side effects, in this case plotting, rather than their return value. Since `plot` only returns NULL it is also the case that `BOD %>% plot` only returns NULL so if we want to keep going in the pipeline we can't.  If instead of `%>%` we use `%T>%` then we still can.

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

BOD %T>%
  plot %>%
  mutate(demand = demand + 1)
```

**2) str**.  Another example is if we want to debug a pipeline by looking at an intermediate result.  `str` does not return anything so if we want to continue in the pipeline we can use `%T>%` .

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

BOD %T>%
  str %>%
  mutate(demand = demand + 1)
```

**3) lm/summary**  Suppose we want to display the output from summary in a pipeline but then go on to calculate the residual sum of squares, i.e. `deviance`.  We want `deviance` to be applied to the output of `lm`, not the output of `print(summary(.))`. Note: when piping into a bracketed expression that `.` must be explicitly used, as seen in `summary(.)`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

BOD %>%
  lm(demand ~ Time, data = .) %T>%
  { summary(.) %>% print } %>%
  deviance
```

**4) lm** Suppose we want to run `lm` on rows 1:4, 2:5 and 3:6 separately.  Then we can use `%T>%` multiple times like this:

```
library(magrittr)

BOD %T>%
  { lm(demand ~ Time, data = ., subset = 1:4) %>% print } %T>%
  { lm(demand ~ Time, data = ., subset = 2:5) %>% print } %>%
  { lm(demand ~ Time, data = ., subset = 3:6) %>% print }
```

This example does illustrate multiple uses of `%T>%` in the same pipeline; however, it could be done even more easily without using any pipelines by making use of `update`.

```
fm <- lm(demand ~ Time, data = BOD)
update(fm, subset = 1:4)
update(fm, subset = 2:5)
update(fm, subset = 3:6)
```

**Alternatives**

It is possible to get the same effect without `%T>%` in other ways.  Using the first example, this runs `plot` explicitly returning the input dot.

```
library(dplyr)

BOD %>%
  { plot(.); . } %>%
  mutate(demand = demand + 1)
```

A second alternative is to break it into two pipelines:

```
library(dplyr)

BOD %>% plot
BOD %>% mutate(demand = demand + 1)
```

A third alternative is to define a function which returns its input:

```
library(dplyr)

plot_ <- function(data, ...) { plot(data, ...); data }
BOD %>%
  plot_ %>%
  mutate(demand = demand + 1)
```

Similar alternatives could apply to the other examples too.

Answer (score 5):

```
library(magrittr)
```

Pipe operator `%>%` returns RHS value

```
c(1, 2) %>% sum
#[1] 3

c(1, 2) %>% sum %>% sqrt
#[1] 1.73205
```

whereas `%T>%` returns the original LHS value

```
c(1, 2) %T>% sum
#[1] 1 2

c(1, 2) %T>% sum %T>% sqrt
#[1] 1 2
```

Comment: I'd also show `c(1, 2) %T>% sum %>% sqrt` to be even clearer.